# Custom action runs with admin privilege and set session variables

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I want to run a custom action and seach registy and then set some session variables after that

heare is my custom action function

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult RegistryDetails(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        CurrentSession = session;

        string registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\XXX\Printers";
        int printerIndex = 1;
        RegistryKey prnKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

        prnKey = prnKey.OpenSubKey(registryPath);

        List<string> subKeyList = new List<string>();
        subKeyList.AddRange(prnKey.GetSubKeyNames());

        while(subKeyList.Contains(printerIndex.ToString()))
        {
            printerIndex++;
        }

        string newRegistryPath = registryPath + "\\" + printerIndex.ToString();
        session["UtillRegKey"] = newRegistryPath;
        session["PrinterNo"] = printerIndex.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        CurrentSession.Log(ex.Message);
        Record exceptionRec = new Record(0);
        exceptionRec[0] = "Errors -" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

but to run this custom action, i need Admin privilages
So I set  `Execute="deferred"` & `Impersonate="no"` of my custom action definition.
That makes `session["PrinterNo"]`&`session["UtillRegKey"]` inaccessible. because it should be `Execute="immediate"` to access session variables.
but I cannot set as `Execute="immediate"`, that will prevent run custom action run as admin.

Can anyone help me to overcome this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify session properties during the deferred (elevated) phase of the installation. You can read session properties during a deferred custom action and it requires a special property set by another custom action and using `session.CustomActionData`

It looks like you are only reading from the registry so there should be no problems doing this as an immediate action.